# What is innerHTML on input elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I'm just trying to do this from the chrome console on Wikipedia. I'm placing my cursor in the search bar and then trying to do `document.activeElement.innerHTML += "some text"` but it doesn't work. I googled around and looked at the other properties and attributes and couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.

The `activeElement` selector works fine, it is selecting the correct element.

**Edit**: I just found that it's the `value` property. So I'd like to change what I'm asking. Why *doesn't* changing `innerHTML` work on input elements? Why do they have that property if I can't do anything with it?

Comment: Just found it, it's the `value` property. But go ahead and answer anyway, maybe it'll help someone else.

Comment: you can add it as an answer yourself

Comment: You can answer your own question actually :)

Comment: More info can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement

Comment: See my edit! I changed the question.

Comment: Works well on forms: http://jsfiddle.net/8x2aN/.

Comment: @FelixKling, ah, I meant `input`, that's my mistake.

Comment: @temporary_user_name this was very helpful. I'm having same problem in 2019

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Setting the `value` is normally used for input/form elements. `innerHTML` is normally used for div, span, td and similar elements.

`value` applies only to objects that have the value attribute (normally, form controls).

`innerHTML` applies to every object that can contain `HTML` (divs, spans, but many other and also form controls).

They are not equivalent or replaceable. Depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: great answr bro. Keep going. My +1

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan here is an example of value in use
js: 
`var a = document.getElementById('info');`
`a.value = 'the earth is round';`
then in your html:
`<input type="text" name="lname" id="info">`

Answer (score 15):

First understand where to use what.

```
<input type="text" value="23" id="age">
```

Here now

```
var ageElem=document.getElementById('age');
```

So on this `ageElem` you can have that many things what that element contains.So you can use its `value`,`type` etc attributes. But cannot use innerHTML  because we don't write anything between input tag

```
  <button id='ageButton'>Display Age</button>
```

So here `Display Age` is the innerHTML content as it is written inside HTML tag button.

Answer (score 6):

Using innerHTML on an input tag would just result in:

```
<input name="button" value="Click" ... > InnerHTML Goes Here </input>
```

But because an input tag doesn't need a closing tag it'll get reset to:

`<input name="button" value="Click" ... />`

So it's likely your browsers is applying the changes and immediatly resetting it.

Answer (score 4):

do you mean something like this:

```
$('.activeElement').val('Some text');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="input" type="number">

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("change", GetData);

function GetData () {
  var data = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log(data);
  function ModifyData () {
    document.getElementById("input").value = data + "69";
  };
  ModifyData();
};
```

My comments: Here input field works as an input and as a display by changing .value

Answer (score 0):

> Each HTML element has an innerHTML property that defines both the HTML
>   code and the text that occurs between that element's opening and
>   closing tag. By changing an element's innerHTML after some user
>   interaction, you can make much more interactive pages.

**JScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Welcome to Stack OverFlow <b id='boldStuff'>dude</b> </p> 
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
```

In the above example b tag is the innerhtml and dude is its value so to change those values we have written a function in JScript

Comment: http://www.design2core.com/myblog/css/how-to-use-new-indian-rupee-symbolwebrupee-on-your-webpage-or-blog/

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML is a DOM property to insert content to a specified id of an element. It is used in Javascript to manipulate DOM.

For instance:
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = "my string";

This example uses the method to "find" an HTML element (with id="example") and changes the element content (innerHTML) to "my string":

HTML
 Change

Javascript

```
function change(){
  document.getElementById(“example”).innerHTML = “Hello, World!”
}
```

After you clicked the button, Hello, World! will appear because the innerHTML insert the value (in this case, Hello, World!) into between the opening  tag and closing  tag with an id “example”.

So, if you inspect the element after clicking the button, you will see the following code :

```
<div id=”example”>Hello, World!</div>
```

That’s all

Answer (score -1):

innerHTML is a DOM property to insert content to a specified id of an element. It is used in Javascript to manipulate DOM.

***Example***.

HTML

> Change

***Javascript***

```
function FunctionName(){
  document.getElementById(“example”).innerHTML = “Hello, Kennedy!”
}
```

On button Click, Hello, Kennedy! will appear because the innerHTML insert the value (in this case, Hello, Kennedy!) into between the opening  tag and closing  tag with an id “example”.

So, on inspecting the element after clicking the button, you will notice the following code :

```
<div id=”example”>Hello, Kennedy!</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
document.querySelector('input').defaultValue = "sometext"
```

Using innerHTML does not work on input elements and also textContent

Answer (score -1):

```js
var lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
lat.value = position.coords.latitude;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="long" class="form-control" placeholder="Longitude">
<button onclick="getLocation()" class="btn btn-default">Get Data</button>
```

Instaed of using InnerHTML use Value for input types