# I am checking the getElementById function behavior it is not returning the output as null

Tags: javascript, html

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <h1 >Shankar Mishra</h1>
  <p id="intro">HelloWorld</p>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var txt=document.getElementById("intro1").innerHTML;
    if(txt==null)
    {
      alert("id doesnot exist");
    }
    document.write(txt);
    alert(txt.nodeName);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I am changing the id name to "intro" it is not returning the node name also
please help me out thanks.

Comment: `document.write`? In 2013?

Comment: Did you change it to `getElementById("intro")` too?

Comment: spell check.! `fucntion`,`doesnot`,`intro1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistake made is

```
  txt=document.getElementById("intro1").**innerHTML**
```

You are checking here node value and saying id doesn't exist
Instead use this

```
  txt=document.getElementById("intro1/intro") //whatever it may be

  if(txt==null){

     alert("id doesn't exist");
  }
  document.write(txt.innerHTML);
  alert(txt.nodeName);
```

Comment: hey thanks it works but can you tell me the concept of innerHTML.y  u have aborted it in document.getElementById("intro1/intro") and introduces it in document.write(txt.innerHTML

Comment: Please check my answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604299/what-is-innerhtml-on-input-elements/20604440#20604440

Comment: And welcome and I am happy that my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var txt=document.getElementById("intro1");
  if(txt === null){
    alert("id doesnot exist");
  } else {
    document.write(txt.innerHTML);      
    alert(txt.nodeName);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1 >Shankar Mishra</h1>
    <p id="intro">Hello World!</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var txt=document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML;

    if(txt=="")
    {
    alert("id doesnot exist");
    }
    document.write(txt);
    alert(txt.nodeName);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```