# jQuery - Appended button is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, append

Please refer - https://jsfiddle.net/QLfxs/142/

```
$("#z").clone().appendTo($("#x"));
```

A button is cloned.
This cloned button is appended inside the text box. The appended button is not visible. Why? and how to get it visible? The input box is acting like a black hole!

Comment: You can't append an element into an input element.

Comment: @SinanGuclu-  No hacky solution?

Comment: What @Cyril has suggested. Put the button and input element within a <div>. Then append to that <div>.

Comment: "The <input> element is empty, it contains attributes only" .If you want to just display the button text in the input box as value, then try `$("#x").val($("#y").text())`

Comment: I've added a  link to a modified version of your jsfiddle to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input val='xx'> 
<button> button </button>
</input>
```

Is equivalent to

```
<input val='xx'></input>
<button> button </button>
```

The closing input tag `</input>` is ignored. So when you try and append a button to within the `<input>` element, it won't appear.

Here is a link to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/QLfxs/144/).

Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp).

Comment: Good supporting link

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the clone button inside the input DOM, which is incorrect.

```
<input type="text" id="x"/>
<div id="n"></div>
<button id="y"> somesome
</button>
```

in JS append to the div

```
 $("#y").clone().appendTo($("#n"));
```

Do it like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/eL57dfj0/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't append element to an input element instead, append next to the element using **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").after($("#y").clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="x"/>
<button id="y">somesome
</button>
```

---

or use **[`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)** method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#y").clone().insertAfter('#x');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="x" />
<button id="y">somesome
</button>
```

---

Refer : [What is innerHTML on input elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604299/what-is-innerhtml-on-input-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append anything to the input element, It will be better if you use `.after` or `.before` in jquery.
So, your solution will be :

```
$("#x").after($("#y").clone())
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#x").after($("#y").clone())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="x">
<button id="y"> somesome
</button>
```