# `innerHTML` not working with `input` tag but `value `does

Tags: html, typescript, innerhtml

I am learning the MEAN stack. I'm performing CRUD operations. I'm stuck with `update`. Not with the operation exactly. Actually before updating a previously posted `article` I want to load contents in text fields for final changes. Those text fields are `title` and `content`. Where `title` is a simple text field and `content` is `quill` text editor value.
Here is my **articles.component.html**

```
Title:<br>
<input type="text" id="title-container" name="title" >
<br>
Content:<br>
<input type="text" id="content-container" name="content">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

and here's my **article.component.ts**
This method is called from somewhere else when I click `edit` button.

```
onPress2(id) {
    this._articleService.fetchArticle(id)
    .subscribe (
      data => {
        document.querySelector('#title-container').innerHTML=data.title;
        document.querySelector('#content-container').innerHTML=data.content;
      }
    );
  }
```

Everything works perfectly if I replace `innerHTML` with `value`. But I cannot do so because my `content` field has value something like `<h1>How to make Cheese cake</h1><br>...` because I am using `quill` text editor. Please tell me what wrong with this code.

Comment: There is no innerHTML for input elements.  
See this answer for more reference:  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20604894/9387017

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r. This solved all my doubts. Though I dont have a good answer to the question. But soon I'll post an answer. thanks.

Comment: Great to hear this.
But did you solved your question?

Comment: Actually I am getting the data. But is showing like this `<b>Some content</b>` while I want it to be rendered like **Some content**

Comment: It might be related to your quill text editor.  
Where excatly are you getting this value? Inside content-contaier textbox?

Comment: In this particular question I am not even using `quill`. Its a normal html form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199807/discussion-between-caffeinatedcod3r-and-tanzeel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research on html elements. Here are my observations and solution.
You cannot use `innerHTML` on `input` tag because it is a self closing tag and `innerHTML` as the name suggests works with tags which have both opening and closing tags For eg. `div`, 'span', etc. So, `innerHTML` and `value` are two different things.

**Solution**

Instead of an `input` tag, you can use `div` and add an attribute `contentEditable="true"` which will make it editable like input field:

```
<div contentEditable="true" id="content-container" value="">
</div>
```

This will solve the problem. And in `ts` file. You are good to use:

```
...
document.querySelector('#content-container').innerHTML=data.content;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you looking for is

```
document.querySelector('#title-container').value=data.title;
document.querySelector('#content-container').value=data.content;
```

Comment: Hmm, Did you try `outerHTML`? Still, If I am not answering sorry for the noise.

Comment: Thanks Sir. But `outerHTML` will not work here. You'll get `document.querySelector(...) is null"`

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` property is used to access or modify the HTML content inside an element. However, the input element is a void element in HTML, which means it cannot have any HTML content or child elements. Void elements, like input, img, or br, do not have closing tags and cannot contain other elements. Therefore, trying to access or modify innerHTML of an input element will not work as expected because it doesn't have any HTML content.