# How to use "as" syntax in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an angular project. It is working perfectly. But it is failing a linting test. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202311/what-is-the-as-syntax-pointed-out-by-tslint) question wasn't very helpful. This the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR: C:/Users/.../monthpicker.component.ts:164:22 - Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead.
Lint errors found in the listed files.
```

And that line 164 is in my ts file:

```
testMethod() {
    this.text = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('rangeInput')).value;
}
```

I'm new to Angular. I don't know what to do. I cant remove `<>` because `rangeInput` is an input element in my HTML:

```
<input id="rangeInput" [ngModel]="text" placeholder="Select range" />
```

Please help me. How to fix this and pass this linting test. I'm using `Node v10.15.3`.

PS: there is no error or warning when this project runs. It happens only during `git push` when it starts linting tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tested this, but usually the syntax would be;

```
testMethod() {
    this.text = (document.getElementById('rangeInput') as HTMLInputElement).value;
}
```

Give that a shot.

Comment: No Sir. `input` is a self closing tag. This will not work. I'm sure. I've tried this previously. :-(

Comment: Sir I'm extremely sorry i think I've misunderstood something. Your answer is working. But I previously had a similar problem. There it was giving some error. I'll tell you that also someday. I'm accepting this for now. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I got it. Here. This one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050900/innerhtml-not-working-with-input-tag-but-value-does.

Answer (score 1):

```
// When stand Alone

// To add before statement
// -/ <intendedType>StatementThatResolves();
const myCanvas1 = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("something");
// To add after statement
// -/ StatementThatResolves() as intendedType;
const myCanvas2 = document.getElementById("something") as HTMLCanvasElement;

// When you need to group use ()

// To add before statement
// -/ <intendedType>StatementThatResolves();
const myCanvasHasWidth1 = (<HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("something")).hasAttribute("width");
// To add after statement
// -/ StatementThatResolves() as intendedType;
const myCanvasHasWidth2 = (document.getElementById("something") as HTMLCanvasElement).hasAttribute("width");
```

For better clarity, try to standardise the casting method you like using linting rules.

Comment: this looks good. I'll try and come back to you if required. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you deletes `document.getElementById` because it could bring a lot of problems when your project become more complex because it is complete outside angular.

If you want to access your `rangeInput` you can just send it to your function. First give it an angular id:

```
<input id="rangeInput" #angularIdExample [ngModel]="text" placeholder="Select range" />
```

and send it to your method. Here I am using a button

```
<button (click)="testMethod(angularIdExample)">testMethod</button>
```

then you can access it in your method giving it the correct type

```
testMethod(inputElement: HTMLInputElement) {
    this.text = inputElement.value;
  }
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sending-input-reference